# Automatically create a Label in Azure DevOps Release Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, label, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I would like to automate Labels creation at the end of the Prod stage in our release pipeline.
I would like to have a Label every time we publish onto production in case we have to make a hotfix but programmers don't always remember to do it.

We use Azure DevOps, TFVC repo. VS 2019, C#.

I looked at Azure CLI and Command Line Script tasks with the "label" command, but it doesn't seems to work. The task runs, but no labels are created.

[Azure CLI code I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXeaK.png)

Could you tell me, please, how to do this? 
I know it is possible to create Labels on every successful build in the Build Pipeline, but I think I would end up with too much useless labels.

Comment: did you solve this? I want to do the same thing.

Comment: Hi did you get a solution for this? If yes, please do share.

Answer (score 0):

In your pipeline go to the Get Sources task:

[image]

Then, if you are using TFVC, you will see an option at the bottom to create a label:

[image]

This then appears in the labels:
[image]